# Can you lock updates which will change too many rows in a database?

Tags: mysql

Is there a way of implementing a rule in mysql which will block updates effecting over 10 rows?

For instance, lets say i have tbl1 with 50,000 rows and I do

```
update tbl1 set tb1.name = 'bob'
```

Then quickly follow on with a "OH NO! I FORGOT THE WHERE!?!?".

The reason I ask is because a junior developer made this mistake and now its repair time :(.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can prevent update (and delete) queries without where clause with this query

```
set sql_safe_updates=1;
```

Take a look at this link

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_safe-updates

i-am-a-dummy is the correct switch for your colleague. :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `LIMIT`

Example

```
update tbl1 set tb1.name = 'bob' LIMIT 0,10
```

This will only update the first 10 rows;

Answer (score 0):

First thing that pops to mind is using transactions where you check affected rows and use ROLLBACK if affected rows are too many or larger than some variable / limit you set. To my knowledge, you can't obtain how many rows would be updated directly. The other option is using LIMIT if it's a single table you're updating. The third solution would be using a test database and slapping the junior developer for forgetting "WHERE" :)

Comment: Start transaction, do the update, check affected rows. If affected rows > 30 (or some other number), rollback. Simple.

Comment: Interesting, how to rollback?

Comment: How about you point out what you think is wrong and we comment and discuss that in order to save time? :)

Comment: No, you misunderstood? I do not know how to implement rollback in database? and I want to learn.